# Can different apps with different signings share the same Account Manager account?

Tags: android, accountmanager

Let's say I have App1 signed with keystore1. And App2 signed with keystore2. They share the same backend for authentication.

We are now implementing Account Manager so both apps share the same account in the device, so the user who downloads App1 and logs in doesn't need to do the same in App2.

But this is only possible if their signature matches.

Is there anything I can do to update App2 signing configuration to match App1? I contacted Google Play support but so far we didn't come to any good solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any update on the issue? I am facing a similar issue with an SDK.